# SASS not compiling in symfony

Tags: css, symfony, sass, assetic

I'm trying to use SASS with the Assetic bundle with symfony. I followed the main tutorial [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html). However, it is not generating any css files. I've tried using different outputs, checking file permissions and messing with filters, but I'm not very sure where to go from here.

The relevant config.yml code:

```
# Assetic Configuration    
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        scssphp: 
          bin: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24
          apply_to: .scss$
```

And this is my stylesheet.html.twig which I include in my base.html.twig

```
{% stylesheets 
    'sass/style.scss' 
    filter = "scssphp" output='css/sass.css' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I tried using the following command line:

```
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
```

And got the following error:

```
[Assetic\Exception\FilterException]                                          
  An error occurred while running:                                             
  '/usr/local/lib/ruby' '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24' '--  
  load-path' '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/my_website/app/../web/sas  
  s' '--scss' '--load-path' '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/my_website  
  /app/../web' '--cache-location' '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/my_w  
  ebsite/var/cache/prod' '/private/var/folders/_2/xkw80vl13zj0xw0nm7j8c4bc000  
  0gn/T/assetic_sassqn8iBF'                                                    
  Error Output:                                                                
  sh: /usr/local/lib/ruby: is a directory                                      
  sh: line 0: exec: /usr/local/lib/ruby: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0    
  Input:
  [...]
```

The remainder of the error was just my scss file. I'm not quite sure what the error is telling me.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find the correct path to `ruby` (that error means `/usr/local/lib/ruby` is not your ruby interpreter, but just a folder) and `sass`.

1. Execute `which ruby`. It will print the path to ruby. For me it's `/usr/bin/ruby`.
2. Setup the correct path in your configuration:

```
    assetic:
        debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
        use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
        ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
        filters:
            cssrewrite: ~
            scssphp: 
            bin: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.24        
            apply_to: .scss$
```

3. If it still doesn't work, probably you need to find the correct path of `sass` too. I'm looking for it in this folders:

   find /usr/local/bin/ | grep sass
   find /usr/bin/ | grep sass
   find /usr/lib/ | grep sass

The first command gave to me this output:

```
/usr/local/bin/sass-convert
/usr/local/bin/node-sass
/usr/local/bin/sass
```

The last line reveals the path. Try to change it in your configuration, like this:

```
assetic:
    debug:          '%kernel.debug%'
    use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
    ruby: /usr/bin/ruby
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        scssphp: 
          bin: /usr/local/bin/sass
          apply_to: .scss$
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Using "which ruby", it still linked me to the same library ( /usr/local/lib/ruby ). However, I used your path, /usr/bin/ruby, as that's where I found the executable. I grepped for sass and found it at the same path as yours. 

Despite all that I still get the same error? It still says " sh: /usr/local/lib/ruby: is a directory ", even though I don't use that path anywhere in the config file. Is there caching involved?

Comment: Maybe, try to clear cache and put the `--env dev ` option to the command